# How to processing the image for tesserac in java?

Tags: java, image-processing, imagemagick, tesseract

I am trying to read characters from a image below using Tesseract:
[image: 33ngg]

And here is my coding for reading the image.

```
Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
        try {           

            String text = tesseract.doOCR(new File(path)); 

            // path of your image file 
            System.out.println(text); 
        } catch (TesseractException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
```

I failed to get the accurate text from the image. So how can i processing the image before reading?

Answer (score 2):

tesseract is not suitable for captcha breaking.

Comment: Any suggest other than tesseract?

Comment: Sure. if your need for access to service is legitimate, contact web provider and ask for API access.